What's the group level range formula in EverQuest?
I'm trying to figure out how to know ahead of time what the level range in a group is so people don't waste their time traveling to my group, just to discover they don't get any experience points (xp).
For example, last weekend in Unrest, we had a level 10 ask to join a group of low-mid teens. The highest member of the group was 17. The level 10 joined for one fight to discover they didn't get any xp.
Yet last night, I was in a group in the Tower of Frozen Shadows and our group ranged from level 28 to level 35. A 7 level difference, just like in Unrest last weekend, but everyone was getting xp just fine.
There has to be some kind of formula to figure it out. So that's my question - What's the group level range formula in EverQuest?

After some searching, I found the answer, so thought I'd share it here in case someone else wonders in the future.
Take the level of the lowest character in the group and multiple it by 1.5, then add + 1, dropping any fractions and rounding down.
There are some caveats, regardless of the formula:

You can always group together if the lowest and highest members of a
group are within 5 levels of each other.
The lowest and highest level characters in a group can never be more
than 30 levels apart.

